# How to upload a file to a specific folder using httpClient

Tags: java, php, file-upload, httpclient

I am trying to upload a zip file to FTP server using Apache HttpClient.

**My java code is like this:**

```
public void doFileUpload(String Localfile, String myurl) {
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
HttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(myurl);
MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.addBinaryBody("file", new File(Localfile));

final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
System.out.println(entity.getContentLength());

httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch (IOException  ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed"+ex);
            Logger.getLogger(FileUpload.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

**In my php File :**

```
if (!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        $dat = time();
    $file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $target_path = $file_name."-".$dat;

if (is_uploaded_file($temp_name)) {
  echo "File ". $target_path ." uploaded successfully.\n";
  move_uploaded_file ($temp_name, $target_path);
} else {
  echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
  echo "filename '". $temp_name . "'.";
  print_r($_FILES);
}
}
```

This works fine if I upload a file to the folder where my php file exists. But In my condition, user will upload their files to their own folder. Example: User A will upload a file to `myftp/upload/A/` or user B will upload a file to `myftp/upload/B/` The target folder is defined from the user end. I can create folder for all the users manually and place a php file in every folder. But how can I do this with a single php file ?